# How to set http_proxy and use it

Tags: linux, go, proxy

How can I set http_proxy in linux from Go? I tried with os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY","ip:port")
also I tried to write to .bash_profile but source .bash_profile is not working and proxy is not set.
Is there a posibility to set the proxy from inside of golang binary when running?

Comment: Env vars are case-sensitive on Linux. Also `os.Setenv()` will only set it within the environment of your program, i.e. not system-wide.

Comment: How can I make it then to work outside of my program? Is it possible?

Comment: Depends. How do you launch the program(s) which you want to have the proxy? If you do it via bash, you need to `export http_proxy ip:port` beforehand. If you do it by double clicking in a file browser, the file browser needs to have it in its environment so the program will inherit it upon launch. (env var inheritance is purely a thing of convention by the way; it's possible to start a process with any env vars desired)

Comment: I launch it via bash, I know if I export http_proxy from terminal before launch the program is working but, my question is if I can set http_proxy in my program.

Comment: Once a process is started, its env vars can only be changed if it provides a mechanism to do so (in the case of Go, by exposing `os.Setenv()` somehow). If you find that setting `http_proxy` has no effect on your program, then that's probably because none of the networking code you are calling cares about it. `http_proxy` is not an OS-wide standard. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212972/463985

Comment: are you making http requests within your code? you can set the proxy in your client

Comment: I know i can set it in client, but I need to change the http_proxy so all the system use it,
also if i export http_proxy before starting program my golang program runs with the proxy but if i try to set http_proxy inside the program my system and my program dosn't use the proxy

Comment: I found out that if a set os.Setenv(proxy) after I make first http request the proxy don't change. But if I set it before, all requests are made through proxy, this partially solved my issue but one still remains, how can I set the proxy after the request